# how do I retrieve a remote webpage whose content has been changed using jQuery/javascript?

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 files here that are located on separate hosts.

test1.php

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init("http://myhost.com/test2.php?tempvar=testonly");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $output;
?>
```

test2.php

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(getURLParameter("tempvar"));
    //$("#test").html(getURLParameter("tempvar"));

    function getURLParameter(name) {
        return (decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search.toLowerCase())||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))).toUpperCase();
    }
});

</script>
<div id="test"><?php echo $_GET['tempvar']; ?> - test</div>
```

As can be seen in test2.php, I am displaying the contents of the URL variable using the PHP echo function. This is working works fine.

My problem is that when I use jQuery (inside test2.php) to change the contents of the page, the curl function is not getting the updated page content.

Any ideas on how to fix this? or perhaps a workaround?

The pages/code I'm using are just an experiment of sorts. So using the echo function is not a problem. **The real webpages/code involved includes code  where page content where manipulated via jQuery.**

I did search the net before coming here and found nothing. I am trying to use http_get PHP function but having server issues which I have reported to our server team.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't use PHP to fetch JS-populated results (they are loaded after the page is loaded). Try PhantomJS / CasperJS.

Comment: This comment is a very good and precise answer to the question.